# How to encode or decode ascii codec?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
   The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: 熔树脂温度(℃)

   'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am trying to encode the ascii character but I am getting error. I have tried with

```
熔树脂温度(℃).encode('utf-8')
熔树脂温度(℃).encode('utf8')
unicode(熔树脂温度(℃),'utf-8')
```

Nothing is working.

Comment: I believe you need unicode not ascii

Comment: `.encode('utf-8')` didn't work? It works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if python-2.7 has unicode enabled though, you'll probably need python3

Comment: Can  you show the actual code? Devil is in the details. Python 3 is much better at unicode than python 2. Is there some reason why you are using this old technology when its been mostly fixed in the new stuff?

Comment: Hello? That isn't python code. It can't produce the error you say. Can you post an example, maybe a few lines from the python shell? I'm going to take a guess, but really you should make this easier for us.

Answer (score 0):

To convert into unicode:

```
In [1]: str1 = '熔树脂温度(℃)'

In [2]: print str1
熔树脂温度(℃)

In [3]: str1
Out[3]: '\xe7\x86\x94\xe6\xa0\x91\xe8\x84\x82\xe6\xb8\xa9\xe5\xba\xa6(\xe2\x84\x83)'

In [4]: unicode_str1 = str1.decode('UTF-8')

In [5]: print unicode_str1
熔树脂温度(℃)

In [6]: unicode_str1
Out[6]: u'\u7194\u6811\u8102\u6e29\u5ea6(\u2103)'
```

Comment: This assumes that OP is running a python shell that is using utf-8. Suppose this was a windows code page?